# Can we migrate TFS 2015 update 2 collection to TFS 2017 update 3.1

Tags: tfs

I have a collection from `TFS 2015 update 2` from `SQL 2014 Enterprise Edition`.  I wanted to migrate this collection to `TFS 2017 update 3.1` and `SQL 2016 Enterprise Edition`.

So I stopped my collection from `TFS 2015` and detached and took the backup of the DB.  I was able to restored the collection to `SQL 2016`.  But when I tried to attach the collection, I got an error `TF254078: No attachable databases were found...`

I do have sys admin from both `TFS server` and `SQL 2016` server.

I also did check the properties and I see as below

`Tfs_Configuration's` properties:

```
•TFS 2017 Update 3.1 
•TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION = 15.17.27414.0
•TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL = Dev15.M125.1
```

`Tfs_defaultCollection` which is from `TFS 2015 update 2` properties:

```
•TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION = 14.95.25122.0
•TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL = Dev14.M95.3
```

Could you please advise what I am missing here that caused the error above?

Appreciate any help I can get!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to attach the TFS 2015 Collection to TFS 2017 after stopping and detach the collection from TFS 2015.  I am not sure why it works this time because I did the steps last time but did not work.